# Error while creating bot

Tags: azure, botframework

I am getting error while creating bot. I am trying to deploy a *Web app bot*. After specifying the name of resource group and their location I click on create. After which bot deployment process starts. But it ends up with an error:

*MsaAppId: MsaAppId is already in use..*

[image]

What can I do successfully deploy a basic bot. This is second time in a week, I am facing something like this on Azure.

**Edit**

Initially I was using **Autocreate MsaAppId & Password** option. That didn't work out (although that used to work)
Then I tried a couple of times with **Create MsaAppId & Password** option. Which takes to a different page to generate AppId & password, and I pasted the new keys in the provided fields.

Still the same result. `MSA App Id already in use`

**Edit 2**
As one of the answer mentioned, I tried creating a separate Bot Registration which I will link up with the Web app later.
But that fails with a weird message saying, App Insights is already deployed, and cannot deploy with same name, when in fact, I have not asked for any new App Insights instance to be deployed. Attaching a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Have you created new app id and password to try again?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating MsaAppId & password. But that also didn't worked. I have edited the question with this detail.

Comment: Hi @MasterChief, I updated the reply, you can refer to it. And you can try to download the deployment template with parameters and deploy resources via powershell etc.

Comment: The team is aware of this issue, and is deploying a fix asap.  Please follow along here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4863

Answer (score 3):

> it ends up with an error:
>
> *MsaAppId: MsaAppId is already in use..*

I have same problem, when I create the web app bot (select Auto create App ID and password option), it failed at creating botServices resource.

*Deployment:*

[image]

*Failed operation details:*

[image]

I also tried to manually create app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and provide App ID and password for creating botService, but the deployment still failed.

[image]

As a workaround, I manually created **Bot Channels Registration** and specify corresponding web application URL as message endpoint, and then modify **Application settings** of that corresponding Azure web site with new **App ID** and **password**, which works for me.

**Note:**

I suspect something wrong with Azure while performing deployment and creating botServices, if possible, you can report it on Azure portal or [create an issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues).

**Updated:**

I click **Automation options** and download the template after I enter the required information/fields for creating a new web app bot, and then I perform deployment by using powershell with downloaded template&parameter file, which work for me, you can try it.

Comment: Hi @Fei Han. It was a good suggestion, but sadly it didn't worked. I have updated the question with what I found.

Comment: I checked the [Deployment details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMvzK.png) and found that there are two progresses of creating same Application Insights resource. Even though my deployment was not failed at creating Application Insights, I still suspect something wrong with Azure portal cause the problem.