# Deployment failure when creating QnA chat bot Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, chatbot

When creating a QnA chat bot I am receiving this error:

`MsaAppId: MsaAppId already in use.. (Code: Invalid Body Data)`

I have no idea what is causing this as I have tried many different names.

Any help provided would be much appropriated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue and is being fixed, refer to the two 
 issues in github, [1](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4863) and [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/264).

You could try to use **Bot Channels Registration** as a workaround, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355440/error-while-creating-bot).